# Snake Game - KeyListener does not work

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

Hey guys I am having trouble with my code. Please ignore any other things that don`t make sense, I still have a lot of work to do...

As you can see below what I did was to change a variable called checkDirection, and then that same variable would be checked.

Check Direction is a private variable... idk if that changes anything

```
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(appleXPosition, appleYPosition, 10, 10);
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(snakeXPosition, snakeYPosition, 10, 10);


        if (checkDirection == 0) {
            snakeXPosition = right(snakeXPosition);
        } else if(checkDirection == 1) {
            snakeXPosition = left(snakeXPosition);
        } else if (checkDirection == 2) {
            snakeYPosition = up(snakeYPosition);
        } else {
            snakeYPosition = down(snakeYPosition);
        }
    }

  @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
        int code = ke.getKeyCode();
        switch (code) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                checkDirection = 0;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                checkDirection = 1;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                checkDirection = 2;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                checkDirection = 3;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Please ignore any other things that don`t make sense"  please make the effort to remove what does not make sense and post [mcve]. Also add what you did to debug the issue.

Comment: `public void paint(Graphics g) { super.paintComponent(g); ... }` is a real problem

Comment: You shouldn't be making logic choices in the rendering phase, these should be taken care of during the "update" phase, rendering should render the current state, nothing else - why? Because that's what it's responsibilities are, also, in Swing a paint pass could be triggered for any number of reasons, many of which you don't control directly. You code should have a "main loop", whose responsibility it is, is to update the state of the game model and schedule a rendering pass, then wait a prescribed amount of time between updates - I'd recommend a Swing `Timer` as simple place to start

Comment: I would also encourage the use of the [key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) of `KeyListener`, it will solve it's unreliability issues

Comment: Thank you @MadProgrammer! I did not really understand... so I put all the code that is intended to update in a different method. But do I call paint again? or I just call repaint?

Comment: @KauePacheco Since you can't call `paint` directly, in Swing, the best you can do is call `repaint`

Answer (score 1):

You update the variable `checkDirection` in this method

`public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {`

but your `paint()` is not scheduled to executed afterward, hence it does not know about new `checkDirection` change.

To scheduled for repaint after your `checkDirection()` is set, call `repain();`

```
 case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            checkDirection = 0;
            repaint(); // Add this
            break;
```

Comment: While this is likely the solution, it's impossible to know, as the OP might have a "main loop" which is scheduling repaints

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with...

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(appleXPosition, appleYPosition, 10, 10);
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillRect(snakeXPosition, snakeYPosition, 10, 10);


    if (checkDirection == 0) {
        snakeXPosition = right(snakeXPosition);
    } else if(checkDirection == 1) {
        snakeXPosition = left(snakeXPosition);
    } else if (checkDirection == 2) {
        snakeYPosition = up(snakeYPosition);
    } else {
        snakeYPosition = down(snakeYPosition);
    }
}
```

You're overriding `paint`, but calling `super.paintComponent`. `paint` itself does a lot of important jobs, calling `paintComponent` is just one of them.

Instead, you should be overriding `paintComponent` directly (and calling it's `super`)

See [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details

Painting should not be making logic decisions, it should simply be painting the current state of the model.  Instead, these decisions should be made as part of a "update" pass performed as part of the "main loop"

The "main loop" would check the state of the input, make decisions about how the state should be updated and schedule a render pass.

A simple place to start might be using a [Swing `Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

I'd also recommend using the [key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) over `KeyListener`, it will fix the unreliability issues associated with `KeyListener`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed guys! Just needed to request focus to the JPanel.